# How to test an app in demo org against new customers?

Tags: appexchange

We have developed an application for SalesForce Marketing Cloud, in demo org. Now we want to test the onboarding flow of the application for new customers, but Salesforce allows just a single demo org for their ISV partner. Please let us know what are the best practices followed in order to test the onboarding flow of new customers. The onboarding flow includes :

1. The user navigating to SalesForce Appexchange, selecting the app and clicking the "Get it Now" option.
2. Installing the app in SalesForce Marketing Cloud.
3. Accessing the application and signing up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to test in [Scratch Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm), which are temporary orgs for development and testing. You get a daily limit for those, but it's much more convenient than creating a permanent org for that purpose.

Comment: I am assuming this is in SFMC, you should create a Demo BU in your org and have the app installed there.

Comment: @sfdcfox Scratch orgs seems to be not for SFMC, but for other Salesforce cloud solutions. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @manjit5190  We had created a demo Business unit. But since our developed app is already in the parent BU, the app is available in child BU as well. This is the problem we are facing as we want to test it afresh for onboarding flow of new customers. Thanks for the comment.